# EOFError when issueing HTTP requests with Ruby

Tags: ruby, http

I'm currently writing a script that iterates over a list of URLs and does some processing on them. One URL in my list is giving me a problem however. The code is as follows:

```
url = "https://secure.www.alumniconnections.com/olc/pub/CDB/events/attendance.cgi?   tmpl=attendance&event=2309515&sort=4"
uri = URI.parse(url)
response = Net::HTTP.get_response(uri)
```

The final line raises the following error:

```
EOFError: end of file reached
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/net/protocol.rb:135:in `sysread'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/net/protocol.rb:135:in `rbuf_fill'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/timeout.rb:67:in `timeout'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/timeout.rb:101:in `timeout'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/net/protocol.rb:134:in `rbuf_fill'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/net/protocol.rb:116:in `readuntil'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/net/protocol.rb:126:in `readline'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/net/http.rb:2028:in `read_status_line'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/net/http.rb:2017:in `read_new'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/net/http.rb:1051:in `request'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/net/http.rb:948:in `request_get'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/net/http.rb:380:in `get_response'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/net/http.rb:543:in `start'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/net/http.rb:379:in `get_response'
    from (irb):5
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/uri/ftp.rb:190
```

No other URLs in my list seem to be giving me any grief. Can anyone explain why I'm getting this error?

Answer (score 6):

I typed in https://secure.www.alumniconnections.com/ which seemed to redirect me to http://www.harrisconnect.com/. My guess would be that your code is not able to handle the redirect. Try using Mechanize (http://mechanize.rubyforge.org/) to handle this. Also I would suggest that you wrap you code in some error handling such as:

```
# Prevent Infinite Loops
counter = 0

begin
  # Your Code Here

rescue EOFError
  puts "encountered EOFError"

  # Fail the connection after 3 attempts
  if counter < 3
     counter += 1
     puts "redo: #{counter}"
     redo
  else
     puts "FAILED CONNECTION #{counter} TIMES"
     counter = 0
  end
end
```

This will attempt to redo the connection which has helped me when connecting to a lot of urls in the past.

EDIT:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'mechanize'

agent = Mechanize.new
html_text = agent.get("https://secure.www.alumniconnections.com/olc/pub/CDB/events/attendance.cgi?tmpl=attendance&event=2309515&sort=4").body

html_file = File.open("html_file.html", "w")
html_file.write(html_text)
html_file.close
```

This writes your webpage to a file just fine for me so give it a try.

Comment: Could your first snippet potentially lead to an infinite loop?

Comment: Yes I believe it could. Somehow I never caught that. I will do a quick edit to fix that although I can't guarantee it will be the best solution.

Answer (score 0):

If it's HTTPS and not just HTTP, you might try this (worked on Ruby 1.8.6):

```
require 'rubygems'
require "net/https"
require "uri"


address = "https://www.your-secure-domain-here.com"
uri = URI.parse(address)
http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
http.use_ssl = true
http.verify_mode = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE
request = Net::HTTP::Get.new(uri.request_uri)
request.basic_auth("username", "password")
response = http.request(request)
```

In my example, instead of `username` and `password` I had to do `SECRET-API-KEY` and `api_token`.

Try it and see if it helps.